# How to pass gradle parameter on IntelliJ sync

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

### EDIT:

Turns out it was not a bug but misconfiguration on my part.

### Original question

Due to [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181700) in IntelilJ I have to add

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude(group = "ch.qos.logback", module = "logback-classic")
    }
}
```

during IntelliJ gradle sync and then not forget to remove it.

Is there a way to pass a param to gradle on IntelliJ sync? I'd be able to have something like this:

```
if (project.hasProperty("intellijHack"))
    configurations {
        all {
            exclude(group = "ch.qos.logback", module = "logback-classic")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Passing command line options to a gradle importer process directly in IDE [is not yet supported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132664#comment=27-843813) (only possible to a Gradle task Run Configuration with the 'Script parameters' field). Please vote and follow this request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132726 But it should work with the gradle.properties file.

Comment: @Andrey problem is if I put it in gradle.properties, gradle when launched from command line will also see it. By the way, it turned out to be gradle bug, not IJ's: https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/590 Also, if you post this information as an answer I'll gladly accept it. Seems there is no way to do what I wanted at the moment.

Comment: Yep, gradle will also use gradle.properties. I hope that the IDEA-132726 request will be soon fixed. And thank you a lot for the work on a bug-report!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing command line options to IDE gradle importer process directly in IDE [is not yet supported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132664#comment=27-843813) (only possible to a Gradle task Run Configuration with the 'Script parameters' field). Please vote and follow [this request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132726).

It should work with the `gradle.properties` file, though this property will also be honored by Gradle, launched from the command line.

**Update(as of April 2023) :** The above issue has been declined. A [related](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132726/Gradle-command-line-options-could-be-provided-for-project-import#focus=Comments-27-3546444.0-0) issue exists at [Ability to control Gradle build environment (using command line or environment variables)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217287) . Please vote and follow the request.